# Java code to create dynamic excel file from a map<header, value> and make it password protected as well at a same time?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, password-protection, password-encryption

I am working on rest service I want to create a dynamic excel file at run time with the help of map, where key of map is header and value is value of the column. Further I want to make it password protected also, once I download it, the file is password protected. I apply password to it and password is also working fine but file is getting corrupted.

[corrupted file warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Zb4.png)

I did lot research but didn't get relevant solution. Please help

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;

`import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionMode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Encryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.vems.util.VEMSUtil;

@Path("/ajaxReport")
public class ReportController {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportController.class);

    private static final String password = "foobar1";

    @GET
    @Path("{attribute1}/{attribute2}")
    @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Response getExcelDownload(@PathParam("attribute1") String attribute1,
            @PathParam("attribute2") String attribute2)
                    throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, GeneralSecurityException {

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        headers.add("Header 1");
        headers.add("Header 2");
        headers.add("Header 3");
        Map map1 = VEMSUtil.getValueMapSMS("1~2~3", "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3");
        List<Map<String, String>> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        valueList.add(map1);
        map.put("header", headers);
        map.put("values", valueList);

        final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        final OPCPackage opc = workbook.getPackage();

        exportExcel(workbook, map);

        StreamingOutput fileStream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                try {
                    // For enc
                    createAndWriteEncryptedWorkbook(workbook, opc, output);
                    workbook.write(output);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(fileStream,
                "application/vnd.ms-excelformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xlsx");
        return response.build();
    }

    private XSSFWorkbook exportExcel(XSSFWorkbook workbook, HashMap<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report Sheet");
        List<String> headers = (List<String>) map.get("header");
        List<Map<String, String>> valueList = (List<Map<String, String>>) map.get("values");
        // Create a blank sheet
        XSSFRow rowHead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
            rowHead.createCell((short) i).setCellValue(headers.get(i));
        }
        int rownum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < valueList.size(); j++) {
            rownum = j + 1;
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
            Map<String, String> valueMap = valueList.get(j);
            Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet = valueMap.entrySet();
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : entrySet) {
                Cell cellFName = row.createCell(colNum, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cellFName.setCellValue(entry.getValue());
                colNum++;
            }
        }
        sheet.protectSheet(password);

        return workbook;
    }

    private void createAndWriteEncryptedWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook, OPCPackage opc,
            OutputStream requestOutputStream) throws IOException {
        // populateWorkbook(workbook);

        try {
            // Add password protection and encrypt the file
            POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem();
            opc.save(getEncryptingOutputStream(fileSystem, password));
            fileSystem.writeFilesystem(requestOutputStream);
        } finally {
            // workbook.close();
        }
    }

    private OutputStream getEncryptingOutputStream(POIFSFileSystem fileSystem, String password) throws IOException {
        EncryptionInfo encryptionInfo = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
        Encryptor encryptor = encryptionInfo.getEncryptor();
        encryptor.confirmPassword(password);

        try {
            return encryptor.getDataStream(fileSystem);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO handle this better
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: so does it work if it's not password protected? have you just tried to save the file to some path on your local post generating it to see if it opens.

Comment: I cannot test your code but what looks strange is, that `createAndWriteEncryptedWorkbook(workbook, opc, output);` writes the encrypted file into the `OutputStream` and then `workbook.write(output);` writes the unencrypted `Workbook` into the same `OutputStream` again.